# Chromecast receiver session_error LOAD_CANCELLED

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I get `session_error LOAD_CANCELLED` when trying to send a 2nd video to the chromecast receiver.

I'm trying to implement a custom receiver to cast videos from my website. 
At this point the application works fine, with all messages being exchanged as expected, except that if I have a video casting, I am not able to load a second video onto the receiver, because of the above error.

According to the documentation, this is expected behaviour (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.media.ErrorType#.LOAD_CANCELLED).

> static cast.receiver.media.ErrorType.LOAD_CANCELLED
>
> Returned when the LOAD request is cancelled by a second incoming LOAD
>   request

However I checked a number of other simpler applications and they all to exactly the same thing when playing a 2nd video: call Load one more time from the sender, and it works as expected.

This is my `onLoad` overwritten:

```
/* Start onLoad event processing */
Receiver.prototype.mediaOnLoadEvent_ = function(event) {
  console.debug('Receiver.js: mediaOnLoadEvent_()');

  var playListener = function(e) {
    document.removeEventListener('video-READY', playListener);

    // BUILDING MEDIAINFO and METADATA HERE
    // .....
    // .....


    console.debug('Receiver.js: sending load complete');
    this.mediaManager_.setMediaInformation(mediaInformation, true, {});
    this.mediaManager_['mediaOrigOnLoad'](event);
  }.bind(this);

  document.addEventListener('video-READY', playListener);
  window.CustomPlayer.loadVideo(event.data.media.contentId,
                                event.data.currentTime, function({});
};
```

this is the messages I get in the console for the receiver when I send the 2nd LOAD request:

```
[ 86.580s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"LOAD\",\"requestId\":54589218,\"sessionId\":\"1B476387-AE78-4F07-BD06-A8CFEF4509A0\",\"media\":{\"contentId\":\"2365405980\",\"streamType\":\"BUFFERED\",\"contentType\":\"\"},\"autoplay\":true,\"currentTime\":0}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"243:client-50611"} cast_receiver.js:13
[ 86.585s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:13
[ 86.591s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received cast_receiver.js:13
[ 86.595s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager load event cast_receiver.js:13
[ 86.602s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending error message to 243:client-50611 cast_receiver.js:13
[ 86.606s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"243:client-50611","data":"{\"requestId\":54589182,\"type\":\"LOAD_CANCELLED\"}"} receiver.js?v=0.2:117
Receiver.js: mediaOnLoadEvent_()
```

As you can see, my `mediaOnLoadEvent` is being called after the `load_cancelled` event was sent, so there's nothing I can do with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is WAI.

In your LOAD request, you have this.
requestId:54589218

In the LOAD_CANCELLED response, you have this.
requestId:54589182

The Request IDs are different.

Your 2nd LOAD is succeeding. It is the *previous* LOAD which is being LOAD_CANCELLED.